# ElasticSearch - How to get the source reference for each fragment highlighted

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlight

I would like to get the reference (it means the full object I see in the _source) from where each fragment highlighted originates.

Example :

- Table = article
- Columns = id, label, content

I would like to know for each fragments highlighted what is the id.

My ElasticSearch request :

```
GET /sa/_search
    {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : {
            "multi_match" : {
              "query" : "oasis",
              "fields" : [ "label", "content" ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "highlight" : {
        "order" : "score",
        "fields" : {
          "label" : { },
          "content" : {
            "fragment_size" : 250
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Currently, with this request, I have only the fragment hightlighted, but I can't know which fragment is link to which id.

Does somebody has any idea to that ?